# On four non-cocyclic integral points on ellipse

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, invariant-theory, diophantine-geometry

Let $(x_i,y_i)\in\mathbb Z^2$ at $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ be four (*not five and I assume an **unique** curve exists because of Diophantine constraints and not geometric constraints*) non-cocyclic integral points on an ellipse in general position whose standard equation of formulation $$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$ has integral coefficients satisfying center $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ and if $T$ is the unique rational linear transformation satisfying

$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2\\y_1&y_2
\end{bmatrix}=T\begin{bmatrix}x_3&x_4\\y_3&y_4
\end{bmatrix}$ then:

1. is $T$ unique in regard to any criteria relating to the ellipse or is $T$ a particular invariant in any sense?
2. if $T$ transforms a particular maximal subset of integral points to another set of equal cardinality satisfying the properties the sets are disjoint and the sets are on the curve then can there be other integral points on the curve?

Comment: I think, ellipse is determined by five points, not four.

Comment: I was thinking something different and I corrected.